# Update Multiple Rows With Different type Values with a Single SQL Query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have 10 field in Database and I have 10 different button in my UI page. I am trying to update my Database field individually. When i click 1 button it will update one field and 2nd for another and so on but using only one SQL update Query. Is this possible in SQL server 2008
If Yes then kindly suggest.

Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE yourtable set
  field1 = COALESCE(@Button1Param, field1),
  field2 = COALESCE(@Button2Param, field2),
  ...
  field10 = COALESCE(@Button10Param, field10)
WHERE Your filter clause
```

And when pressing the Button1 provide value only for @Button1Param parameter to the query, leaving others = DBNull.Value

So, you have not to use dynamic or multiple different queries

Answer (score 0):

Only through dynamic SQL, and still then not quite trivial.

You would need code attached to each button that says which column it represents, so your query would look something like

```
DECLARE @SQL = NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE [db].[dbo].[table] SET ' + @__upd_button_col + ' = ''' + @__upd_button_Value + ''' WHERE ID = ''' + @__upd_ID + ''''
sp_executesql @SQL
```

However this is really bad design (unless specifically required by your requirements). Why don't you edit your 10 fields then have -one- commit button in your application and update all columns at once?